# Foursquare save button in google maps marker?

Tags: javascript, foursquare

The idea was to load all the Foursquare locations from a list into Google maps and allow other people the add them to their own lists by clicking on the "save to foursquare button". But I ran into a few issues when I tried to use them inside a Google maps marker.

The script that you use from Foursquare ( https://foursquare.com/business/brands/offerings/savetofoursquare ) doesn't seem to find the "save to foursquare button" link when it's placed inside a Google maps marker, it's unstyled. And when you click the link it doesn't open in a light box, but in a new page. I can style the button with some CSS. But the light box is a different story, I could open one, but how would you know when to close it?

If I test the "save to foursquare button" on a single page without Google Maps, the light box closes automatically after saving the location. But I don't think there is a way to detect when to close it again if you opened one from a marker

But even better of course would be if the "save to foursquare button" would be detected by the script in the first place. Anyone ever tried to get the "save to foursquare buttons" to work in Google maps markers? All tips are welcome :)

You can see what I mean here http://tijmensmit.com/foursquare/ the button is unstyled, and no light box either.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Include the Foursquare SDK as on https://foursquare.com/business/brands/offerings/savetofoursquare

Unminify Foursquare's widget.js to find out what it really does at DOM ready.
Here's what Foursquare actually does :

```
go: function (a) {
    a = g.findMarkers(a);
    e.each(a, function (a) {
        var c = g.markerConfig(a),
        b = g.instance(c);
        "false" == c.replaceButton ? b.attach(a) : b.replace(a)
    })
},
```

Write your own function :

```
// My function to replace "new" Foursquare save buttons
// @param e : <a class=fourSq-widget> element
function myFoursquareReplaceSave(e) {
    if (typeof e != "undefined") {
        var f = window.fourSq.widget.Factory;
        var c = f.markerConfig(e);
        var b = f.instance(c);
        "false" == c.replaceButton ? b.attach(e) : b.replace(e);
    }
}
```

Finally call the function each time a new GMap Infobox is created.
Something like :

```
// t is the Infobox (a google.maps.OverlayView),
// div is the <div> element (the content)
// (using jquery)
myFoursquareReplaceSave($(t.div).find('.fourSq-widget').get(0));
```

I haven't tested the domready listener for infowindows :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505179/229088