# Unable to trigger click event in infowindow in google maps using angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to make a click work in infowindow in google maps. I'm unable to achieve with the following code. Can somebody tell me where I'm doing wrong?

```
loadmap(){
    var locations = [];var map;
     for(var i=0;i<this.data.length; i++){
         locations.push({
             'location_name':this.data[i].location_name,
         });
     }
     var marker; var icon;
     map   = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.4637, 3.7492),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    map.markers = [];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
       enableEventPropagation: true
    });
     for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {         
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng('lat', 'lng'),
                map: map,
            });              
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {          
                return function() {              
                    infowindow.setContent(
                        '<span>'+locations[i].location_name+'</span><br/>'+
                        '<input type="button" id="infowindow_submit" name="submit" value ="submit"/>'
                    );
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
               };
            })(marker, i));
            google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
                $("#infowindow_submit").submit(function() {
                    console.log("hi!");
                });
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of this doesn't really look like Angular code... Where is `infowindow` defined? Are you struggling with getting anything to happen with just the pure JS event handlers or having trouble integrating it into Angular. I'd imagine there might be Google Maps npm packages that integrate better with Angular, although I haven't looked. Are you getting any console errors? Can you put a breakpoint or `console.log` inside the click handler and see if that code is getting executed?

Comment: I'm using pure JS code to display maps in my angular project. I'm not getting any errors in console and also nothing is happening when I click the button in infoWindow. click handler for marker is being executed but not the infowindow domready part. That part is not being debugged too

Comment: I think your problem may be that `infowindow` is not defined. Do you have any more code? The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416160/listening-for-the-domready-event-for-google-maps-infowindow-class seems to create a variable named that.

Comment: @ScottyWaggoner I've updated my code... defined infoWindow but still the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is you are using a button but trying to add a form event listener.

`$("#infowindow_submit").submit(() => console.log("hi!"))` works for forms but not for single buttons.

Are you looking for `$("#infowindow_submit").click(() => console.log("hi!"))`?

I believe your comment may be contradictory which is what led me to notice the above issue.

> nothing is happening when I click the button in infoWindow. click
>   handler for marker is being executed but not the infowindow domready
>   part

If you are clicking a button in the Info Window, the `domready` event should have fired already. I thought you couldn't get the Info Window opened at all. Guess I didn't read that right the first time... You don't have a `console.log` there and didn't say you tried to put a breakpoint there. The `console.log` you do have is inside the `submit` event but you don't have one inside the `domready` event function. Hopefully that `domready` is actually getting fired.

Comment: Hey thank you. That was a mistake from my side. It's working now. you're right. I should have used click